# Applying multiple filters using Geoserver SLD styling

Tags: geoserver, sld, filter, xml

I have vector point data being served via Geoserver, with layer styling being applied using an SLD stylesheet. I've created a number of [styling rules](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rules.html) to symbolise these points, and I'd like to customise these rules by [filtering](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html) each point by four individual attribute fields so that the points are only shown on the map when all four tests are `True`.

I have tried to achieve this by including all four of my filter tests inside a `<ogc:And>` [logical operator](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html#logical-operators):

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:And>
        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>rate_time</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>-2.5</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>rate_time</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>-1.0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
        <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>sig_time</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>0.01</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>valid_obs</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
    </ogc:And>
</ogc:Filter>
```

However, this is not working correctly, as some points continue to show on the map despite at least one of the four tests returning `False`. I suspect this is because `<ogc:And>` only supports two filter operator elements:

> The content for "And" and "Or" is two filter operator elements [[link](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html#logical-operators)]

What is the recommended way to apply multiple (e.g. four in this particular case) attribute tests within a single Geoserver SLD filter?

Answer (score 3):

I think unfortunately, you need to do lots of nesting... XML is verbose.

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <ogc:And>
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>rate_time</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>-2.5</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
        <ogc:PropertyName>rate_time</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>-1.0</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
    </ogc:And>
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>sig_time</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>0.01</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
        <ogc:PropertyName>valid_obs</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:And>
</ogc:Filter>
```

Comment: Just a side note: The annoying limit of two conditions per logical operator is not a result of the verbosity of XML. It seems to actually be a problem with the Geoserver implementation of the OGC SLD standard, because the standard says a BinaryLogicOpType can have two or more sub-elements but Geoserver docs say there is a limit of two.